# pgAdmin - "cannot open logfile!" (WINDOWS 10; Postgres 9.4)

Tags: postgresql-9.4, pgadmin-3

Our Windows 10 clients have both PostgreSQL 9.4 and pgAdmin3 (v1.22) installed.

I keep receiving the **FATAL: "Cannot open the logfile!"** error by invoking pgAdmin3 in either
of the following EXE locations.

1. C:\Program Files(x86)\pgAdmin III\1.22\pgAdmin3.exe
2. C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pgAdmin3.exe

The problem is that when pgAdmin3 starts the pgAdmin splash screen will not dismiss and you cannot gain
access to configure the postgresql.conf file.  I'm assuming the log file its looking for is pgAdmin.log but if I navigate to `C:\Users\<user_id>\Documents\postgresql` I cannot find such a log file.  I tied to create an empty pgAdmin.log file whith not luck of gaining proper entry into pgAdmin3.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to identify the value of %APPDATA% on your WINDOWS system.
Change directory to %APPDATA%
Does the folder postgresql exist?  If not create the folder with this name.
Chand directory into postgresql
Does the folder pgAdmin exist?
if not create the folder with this name (note the capital "A").
In here copy the postgresql.conf file from your Postgres or pgAdmin installation folder
Create an empty pgAdmin3.log file in here
Done